# Can't find "updater" on ImageJ 1.49

Tags: plugins, imagej

Sorry for this question, but have been trying to figure it out for a while...

I'm trying to install a SIOX for ImageJ using the `updater`, but the update option (`Help > Update imageJ`) don't show any option to get plugins directly from the web, only to update ImageJ. and can't find any other link to an "updater" as suggested in the main page.

So, I downloaded a jar file `Siox_Segmentation-1.0.5-20160117.192327-11.jar` and copied it into plugins/jars, re-open ImageJ... but it didn't work either. I'm working with MacOSX and ImageJ 1.49 installed using home brew.
Thanks for any advice.

Carlos Alberto

Comment: Kind of solve the problem using the Fiji installation...

Comment: Interesting; I did not know there was a Homebrew cask for ImageJ. I wonder who maintains that... it's not the core ImageJ developers. And apparently it is not ImageJ2, as you discovered. I would recommend against installing ImageJ using Homebrew for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ImageJ updater](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-updater) functionality is part of [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) (which includes full backwards compatibility to ImageJ 1.x and is also part of Fiji, as you discovered).

You can download vanilla ImageJ2 from [here](http://imagej.net/Downloads).

Information on [how to follow an update site](http://imagej.net/How_to_follow_a_3rd_party_update_site) is available on the ImageJ wiki.

---

For general usage questions about ImageJ, the [**ImageJ forum**](http://forum.imagej.net/) is the best place to ask.